# как вставить JSON объект много раз на веб странице

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

у меня есть 3Д объект на JSON файле и хотел использовать его на веб странице, но проблема в том что когда я вставлю его много раз то он загружается каждый раз. есть ли способ чтоб загрузился один раз и в повторном использование не загружать и использовать загрузившийся JSONа.